# Terminal command follows the lifetime of another terminal command

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism

What I would like to achieve is a bash script or even better a single bash line that can run two terminal based apps on parallel. I am aware of the commands `&` and `;` but in my case they are not applicable because both my commands keep the terminal open and need each other to run properly. 
It might seem like an edge case but my specific use case is quite simple and I think it might be help full in many similar cases.

What I am trying to do is to parse a message from a usb port that uses swo protocol ,so my quite obnoxious workaround is :

1. Open terminal one , run `openocd -f connect_swo.cfg` (terminal1 hangs )
2. Open terminal two , run `python3 swo_parser.py` (terminal2 hangs and terminal1 prints values)
3. Then terminating both commands with two separate `ctrl+c` signals

Expected solution would be something like:

1. Run magic command that open two connected sessions and both my commands on the seperate sessions
2. One single `ctrl +c` terminates both commands

PS:Comment me if I should move the question to superuser

Comment: "both my commands keep the terminal open" ... Do they really need the terminal? What happens if you do `openocd -f connect_swo.cfg& python3 swo_parser.py`? Does either command fail to work?

Comment: @muru Yes it fails as openocd needs the terminal to print the resaults and swo_parser need the terminal for error (To be honest I don't care about the second terminal and I could supress it with something like 2&>1 /dev/null but even then the first command's terminal closes to open the second command's, another workaround could be to change the order of the commands but then command one fails as there is no open usb connection and it autoterminates)

Comment: What about something like `(sleep 5 ;  python3 swo_parser.py) & openocd -f connect_swo.cfg`?

Comment: @muru Yey ,This works perfect ,thanks,How can I accept a comment as an answer though?

Comment: Actually not that perfect ,now ctrl +c terminates only first app and second app is out of control (even with multiple ctrl c) on the vs codes terminal ( on the default it works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Parallel you should be able to do this:

```
parallel --tty -j0 ::: 'openocd -f connect_swo.cfg' 'python3 swo_parser.py'
```

If GNU Parallel is not already installed look at: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: All three solutions are fine but I will accept this one as it is the more elegant,It's the only one that closes both programs with one button and it gives me the choice to multithread (if I am correct and j2 means what I think it means).My only question is :parallel is not a default linux command ,when I typed this command my terminal complained that I should install moreutils or parallel ,which of the packages is more relevant for my job?(I guess the second by the name)

Comment: GNU Parallel is not part of moreutils.

Comment: Out of topic:That's a pitty they should package your parallel with moreutils ,from now on I will declare myself a fan of you <3

Comment: If you look at the history, I actually tried to get that to happen in 2009: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a program like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Answer (score 1):

If `openocd` absolutely needs TTY connected to stdin, and the Python script needs to be run after `openocd`, you can reverse the order of execution by using `sleep` to delay the start of the script execution:

```
(sleep 5 ; python3 swo_parser.py) & openocd -f connect_swo.cfg
```

A single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will not terminate both, but there might be a way around that using `trap`s. Or something like:

```
(sleep 5 ; python3 swo_parser.py) & openocd -f connect_swo.cfg
kill %1
```

Comment: Nice with the kill %1 it even works in the nested terminal of vscode even though I don't have an idea what it does

Comment: It `kill`s the first background job (`%1`).